# How to place the "i" in a loop before and after a $

Tags: r

I am trying to write a little for loop to help me load some data and assign values to objects.
But I've stumbled onto a problem. I can't figure out how to correctly place the "i" in a for loop before and after this sign $.

Here is a little example:

Let's say I want to load some specific .RData files and after I loaded the files I want to append a new column filled with the value "NULL".

```
for( i in c(1,2,3,4,5)){
  load(file = paste(DATA, paste(getwd(), "/Group", i ,".RData", sep=""), sep=""))
  assign(paste("Group", i, "$new_c", sep=""), NULL)
}
```

This code just creates new objects called for example Group1$new_c.

I also would like to know how I could place the "i" by assigning from a list.

Like this for example:

```
for( i in c(1,2,3,4,5)){
  assign(paste("Group", i, sep=""), List$`i`)
}
```

Does anyone know the answer to my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically work with column names, don't use `$` — use `[[`. For example

```
for(df in list_of_data_frames) df[["new_c"]] <- NULL
```

Separately, you should be aware that assigning `NULL` into a column doesn't make a new column full of `NULL`s, it *deletes the column*. Use NA for a "not-present" value.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. It is not pretty but does the job i think.

```
a <- list(a=2,b=3,c=4)
i = "b"
eval(parse(text=paste0("a$",i)))
[1] 3
```

Edit: spelling

Comment: `eval-parse-text` combinations are generally advised against in R programming. They aren't necessary in this instance, and could lead to unintended code execution if column names are not as expected (R-injection attacks are not yet a common attack vector, but still)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `for` when possible:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
data <- paste0("Group:",data)
```

But if it's necessary then the answer is:

```
for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
  assign(paste("Group", i, sep=""),i)
}
```